# What determines the SAK of a Mifare device?

Tags: rfid, mifare

I have a Mifare fob and a magic Mifare Classic card. When I fully clone the fob onto the card, the SAK found from the card is `0x88`, despite a SAK of `0x08` on the fob.

If I change the sixth byte of block 0 on the card from `0x88` to `0x08`, the SAK changes accordingly. However, the fob holds a value of `0x88` at that position whilst reporting a SAK of `0x08`. So, what determines the SAK such that two cards with supposedly identical data can report different values for it?

Comment: The ManufactureCode contains: ProductionCode | Size, TagType ... | SNR so may be your card is a 4k Classic and your copy 1k and the 6th Byte is the size of the card. What not identifies why your magic card doesn´t take the new data what it suppost to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had:

- An original TAG (mifare 1k)
- A chinese TAG (mifare 1k) `gen1a` with block 0 rewritable.

From the [Rfid Research Group documentation](https://github.com/RfidResearchGroup/proxmark3/blob/master/doc/magic_cards_notes.md) we can found this information:

```
MIFARE Classic block0:

11223344440804006263646566676869
^^^^^^^^                         UID
        ^^                       BCC
          ^^                     SAK(*)
            ^^^^                 ATQA
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Manufacturer data
(*) some cards have a different SAK in their anticollision and in block0: +0x80 in the block0 (e.g. 08->88, 18->98)
```

so usually the `SAK` is determined by the bytes #6 of the block 0.

But as specified in the doc, some cards have a different SAK in their anticollision and in block0.

So unfortunately my chinese TAG `gen1a` was unable to reproduce the same behavior of my original TAG. Also a `gen1a` TAG accept `magic command`, which means that a backdoor exist with those tags and you can read or write a block without using the access key, this backdoor is now well known and some reader can detect that.

The solution was to use a `gen2` TAG aka `CUID card`, with block 0 rewritable. This TAG add a `08` SAK, by default, that did not change, even if a rewrite the byte #6 of the block 0.

Answer (score 2):

The SAK byte identifies the manufacturer code and product code.
x08 would be NPX mifare clasic 1k and
x88 would be Infineon mifare clasic 1k
You would need to clarify with your card supplier which one does he sale.

source: http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=ISO14443A

Comment: Are their more SAK byte identifiers then x08 and x88?